# Build customised flag and flag patterns in mvc in ecommerce application

Tags: jquery, css, image-processing, html5-canvas, imagemap

We have following requirement.
We are developing one project in asp.net but confuse about the way how we can do it.
One of our client needs the web site that offers custom flags building. The example of flag is attached with this question. Here i want to give user a ability that user can buy flags. For this option i will use one of open source shopping cart. But don't know how we will ability to user that part-1 will be of red color, part-2 of different color etc.

They can choose any color from color selection box and do checkout from there.
The flag patterns will be added from admin area of our shopping cart admin panel. But confuse here how we will add new patters?
In which format? So user can fill color from color box in it and proceed for checkout.
How to add this type of patterns from admin? They also want to add different shapes for flags.
Client refuse to use flash for it.
Example front-end is below.

[image]

Comment: You don't need image processing to select 3 colors.  Just use an html table containing colored divs and then listen for click events to add the color to your 1-2-3 color selections.

Comment: thanks for your response. but my question is how do i make dynamic petterns?

Comment: You're welcome. I added a simple demo of creating, displaying and selecting flag colors below.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add divs with background-colors and select color choices from them (see example code below).

If you want to hook into MVC:

- Send the colors array from your controller into the view's model.
- Add a 'Continue' button that sends the users 3 color selections to your POST controller.

```js
var currentColor=1;
var colors=[];
colors.push({color:'#04a09c',label:'turquoise'});
colors.push({color:'#862a77',label:'wineberry'});
colors.push({color:'#1e3a81',label:'o.g.blue'});

for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++){
    var $newDiv=$('<div/>',{
        id:colors[i].label,
    });
    $newDiv.css('background-color',colors[i].color);
    $newDiv.addClass('color');
    $newDiv.appendTo('#colors')
    $newDiv.data('label',colors[i].label);
}

$('.color').on('click',function(e){
    var $color=$('#color'+currentColor);
    var bkcolor=$(this).css('background-color');
    var colorName=$(this).data('label');
    $color.css('background-color',bkcolor);
    $color.text(currentColor+" = "+colorName);
    if(++currentColor>3){currentColor=1;}
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#choices{width:150px;border:1px solid red;color:white;font-size:18px;background-color:lightgray;}
#colors{display:inline-block;}
.choices{width:150px;height:35px;border:1px solid gray;}
.color{display:inline-block;width:50px;height:35px;border:1px solid gray;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>These are your 3 choices</p>
<div id=choices>
  <div id=color1 class=choices>1</div>
  <div id=color2 class=choices>2</div>
  <div id=color3 class=choices>3</div>
</div>
<p>Click 3 colors below to choose them above</p>
<div id=colors></div>
```

Comment: thank you once again for your reply this is front end to full fill requirements and  i want to know admin side UI how works for upload dynamic patterns. because my client is only upload image not create div for that

Comment: @markE I need something similar, how to do same for custom shapes?

Comment: @JatinGadhiya The administrative side of this "color picker" is simply having the admin assign `color` and `label` for each available color. You don't give much details about your design, but, for example, if you're using EntityFramework (EF) you can use code-first to create your Colors POCO (your data model). Then Visual Studio will scaffold out all the admin stuff for you (controllers, views, CRUD, etc).   Then your FlagColorPickerController will fetch all available colors from the database and send those color to the FlagColorPickerView's model for the user to choose their colors.

Comment: @Krunal You can use the same concept to let the user choose their custom shape of their flag.  Simply put an image of each custom flag shape inside each div. Then the user can click-select their desired shape.

Comment: @markE Thank you for your response. But I am not getting which same concept you are referring? Can you please clarify it a little more?

Comment: @Krunal Here's the colors example modified to select shapes: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/1n27ed9e/

Comment: @markE Thank you for your response. This is helpful, but yet not getting idea. I have custom shape in my image - not circle / square / or triangle... they are custom shape. And I want to allow customer to select shape and color for it similar to flag originally posted in question, but not only for flat.. for my custom shapes! Can you give me some hint on how to do something similar for custom shape?

Comment: @Krunal The customer has to see your custom shapes so that they can choose from them.  You can use your favorite image processing app to create your custom images--even something like Paint/Paintbrush will let you create the custom shapes you offer to your customer.  So draw all your custom shapes in separate images.  Then show the customer your variety of custom shapes using code in my jsFiddle.  Your customer clicks on their desired custom shape from the grid of images you provide. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @markE Thank you for your response! I think you didn't understand my question. Let me clarify. Everything you say is correct, but the issue is if I have image which has custom shape, how can I select one part of shape and fill colour into it? For example, http://i.stack.imgur.com/voEOR.jpg is a flag with 1,2,3 boxes. My image includes custom shape as 1,2,3! Not a box!